# Cloning a GitHub repo with Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, github

I am trying to learn Swift and I am watching some youtube videos that links to GitHub repos for code to practice with. When I clone a repo to my Xcode I get this error below, is it because of copyright? not possible for me to copy or modify this code to make it my own? How can I get this error to disappear?

"Failed to create provisioning profile.
The app ID "com.robcanton.FirebaseApp" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again."

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna use something else not com.robconton.FirebaseApp cause it’s already taken.
Change the value under bundle identifier that’s unique for each app

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error due to bundle identifier which is there in the project is not linked with your provision profile.

To get rid of this error, you may use your own provision profile and bundle id, or try to run the app on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a unique bundle identifier as `com.robconton.FirebaseApp` is already taken. For example, you can use **`com.robconton.FirebaseApp1`** or something like **`com.robconton.trulsTestApp`**.

The point is that the bundle identifier has to be unique as it provides an identity to your app.